# React Native: Reset children states from grandfather?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, native

This is a tricky question. Lets say I have a Component `<GrandFather />` with a `<Form />` Component inside. The `<Form />` has Multiple `<Input />` Components. The `<Input />` has an internal useState. At the `<GrandFather />`, there are some functions like loadForm(loading some fields) and unloadForm(removes these fields). On the unloadForm I wanna reset the internal State of the Inputs. The only solution I found was to have a key on the `<Form />` and increment it on unload, so thats forces the rest. Is there a better good way to do this without change the logic? P.S I 'm using Typescript.

```
function GrandFather (props: Props) {
    const loadForm = () => // load some fields to the formData
    const unloadForm = () => // unload these fields to the formData

    return <Form formData={formData}/>
}

function Form (formData: FormData) {
  return (
  <>
      <Input /> // with some props
      <Input /> // with some props
      <Input /> // with some props
  </>
  )
}

function Input (props: Props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(false);
    // the state here is being used for styling and animations, at 
    // somepoint it will became true
    return <TextInput {...props}/>
}
```

any way here to reset this state to all the inputs on the function unloadForm?

Comment: Can you share a code for example?

Answer (score 1):

I see two different methods of achieving this.

---

#### Method #1

As an example, I'll use a simple login form.

So you could define the following state variables on `GrandParent`:

```js
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
```

Then, pass all `username`, `setUsername`, `password`, and `setPassword` as props to `Form` and then on to the `Input` components.

Inside of the `Input` component, you could turn the inputs into controlled inputs by adding the following:

```js
<input type="text" value={username} onChange={setUsername} />
```

If you ever need to clear the inputs, you could call right directly from `GrandParent` or `Form` (or anywhere where you have access to the setters) the following:

```js
setUsername('');
setPassword('');
```

---

#### Method #2 (hacky)

You could define, on `GrandParent`, a state variable that, as the above method, you would pass both the variable and setter as props to `Form` and then to each `Input`:

```js
const [clear, setClear] = useState(false);
```

Then, inside the `Input` component, assuming you have a `value` state variable on it (with the equivalent setter `setValue`), you could set up a listener for a change on the state variable `clear`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (clear === true) {
    setValue('');
  }
}, [clear]);
```

Then, whenever you wanted to clear all the input values, you could call, from anywhere:

```js
setClear(true);
setTimeout(() => { // the setTimeout might not be required
  setClear(false);
}, 1);
```